# Is there a better way to get pointers to elements of std::vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, stdvector

I'm aware that `std::vector<bool>` is a weird specialization of `std::vector` that, among other things, has the downside of it being impossible to get pointers/references to individual elements.

I had a situation where I needed pointers to elements. Using  `std::deque<bool>` wasn't ideal because of the extra deref, and `std::vector<unsigned char>` wasn't ideal because I was working with `std::any`s that would yell at me unless I fully committed to never referring to my bools as bools.

Since typing `using Bool = unsigned char` is far too much effort for me to be expected to do, I instead decided to make a helper class that effectively works as a pointer to elements of `std::vector<bool>`:

```
//Vector Bool Pointer - Helper class used for getting/setting bools put into vectors using pointers
class VBP {
public:
    VBP() {
        ptr = nullptr;
        mask = 0;
    }

    VBP(std::vector<bool>::reference ref) { 
        /* 
            std::vector<bool>::reference is the actual type returned when you index a 
            std::vector<bool>, it just has an implicit cast to bool:

            constexpr operator bool() const noexcept {
                return (*_Getptr() & _Mask()) != 0;
            }

            constexpr const _Vbase* _Getptr() const noexcept {
                return this->_Myptr;
            }

            constexpr _Vbase _Mask() const noexcept {
                return static_cast<_Vbase>(1) << this->_Myoff;
            }

            Since we can pass references around, we can store from them the necessary information
            to effectively dereference them later.
        */
        ptr = (unsigned*)ref._Getptr();
        mask = static_cast<std::_Vbase>(1) << ref._Myoff; //I want to know whose idea it was to make
        //_Mask() a protected function but leave _Myoff public.
    }

    VBP& operator=(const VBP& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            this->ptr = other.ptr;
            this->mask = other.mask;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    VBP& operator=(const bool& other) {
        if (ptr != nullptr && (bool)(*ptr & mask) != other) {
            *ptr ^= mask;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const VBP& other) {
        return this->ptr == other.ptr && this->mask == other.mask;
    }

    bool operator==(const bool& other) {
        return ptr && (*ptr & mask) == other;
    }

    operator bool() {
        return ptr && *ptr & mask;
    }

    bool operator !() {
        return !ptr || !(*ptr & mask);
    }
private:
    unsigned* ptr;
    std::_Vbase mask;
};
```

This class works, and I personally don't have any issues with it, but I know that the way `std::vector<bool>` works is implementation-dependent, so I'm not sure how much of what I do here would be possible on another machine. Stuff like `_Myoff` being public while `_Mask()` is protected, for example, seem like a weird design choice that I wouldn't be able to rely on more generally.

Is there any way to implement pointers to elements of `std::vector<bool>` which would work no matter how it is implemented?

Comment: Can't imagine the use case for this. IMO completely not portable voodoo.

Comment: And how you gonna use it, provided you don't know what `std::vector<bool>`stores in memory (it's likely a bit representaiton) and in which order? it doesn't contain `bool`s

Comment: And if you replace `bool`  by any other type, you would run into an issue that `if(bool_value)` and `if(bool_value==true)` not always do same thing. You're trying to build an automated factory of garden rakes for you to step on. C++ specificatlly got special cases for expressions with result of `bool` and for types convertible to `bool`.

Comment: `enum class Bool { False, True }; std::vector<Bool> my_bool_vector;`

Comment: @Eljay I once did `enum class Bool { False = false, True = true, Unknown };` because I needed  "ternary" one. At least it allows "safe-ish" conversion if needed

Comment: You seem to grasp a lot of C++ to not know that std::vector<bool>::iterator is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector<bool>::iterator` has the semantics that is pretty close to a pointer to `bool`, including the ability to assign a new `bool` value to vector's elements via the indirection.

Here is an example that illustrates this approach:

```
std::vector<bool> vb {true, true, false, false, true, false};
std::cout << vb.size() << std::endl;
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != vb.size() ; i++) {
    std::vector<bool>::iterator ptr = std::next(vb.begin(), i);
    std::cout << "before " << *ptr << " ";
    *ptr = !(*ptr);
    std::cout << "after " << *ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Both the read via `*ptr` and a write via `*ptr = ...` work as expected.

[Live demo.](https://ideone.com/Q26lbM)